# Java - Class.isInstance() always returns false

Tags: java, class, reflection, instanceof

In my GameObject class I have the following method to check if the GameObject would be colliding with another object if it moved to the specified position:

```
public boolean collisionAt(Vector2d position, Class<? extends GameObject>... exclusions) {
    if (getBounds() == null)
        return false;
    Rectangle newBounds = getBounds().clone();
    newBounds.setPosition(position);
    // Check collisions
    for (GameObject object : new ArrayList<>(gameObjects)) {
        if (object.getBounds() != null && newBounds.intersects(object.getBounds()) && object != this) {
            boolean b = true;
            for (Class<? extends GameObject> exclusion : exclusions) {
                if (object.getClass().isInstance(exclusion))
                    b = false;
            }
            if (b)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to allow the program to define exclusions, for example if I don't want this method to return true if it collides with a Spell. But for some reason the Class.isInstance() line always returns false. I even tried this:

```
System.out.println(Spell.class.isInstance(Spell.class));
```

and the console outputs false! What's going on here?

Comment: Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)). When using isInstance, it only returns true if the argument is an instance of that class, not if the argument is the same class object. `Spell.class.isInstance(new Spell())` returns `true`. You aren't passing it an instance of that type, so it's returning `false`

Comment: This is the declaration for java.lang.Class.isInstance() method-
`public boolean isInstance(Object obj)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `isInstance` tests if the given object is an instance of the `Class`, not if the given `Class` is a subclass of the `Class`.

You have your invocation backwards.  You need to test if the `gameObject` is an instance of one of the exclusion classes.

```
if (exclusion.isInstance(gameObject))
```

Answer (score 7):

From official Javadocs

```
public boolean isInstance(Object obj)
```

Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator. The method returns true if the specified Object argument is non-null and can be cast to the reference type represented by this Class object without raising a ClassCastException. It returns false otherwise.

You need to pass in the object of class rather than the class itself.

Example

```
SomeClass object = new SomeClass();
System.out.println(SomeClass.class.isInstance(object));
```

Comment: I think it would be proper to write **Someclass** instead of **Someobject** because its the class name that we are specifying here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass in an instance of the class in question rather than a class literal. E.g.

```
Spell spell = new Spell();
System.out.println(Spell.class.isInstance(spell));
```

Answer (score 0):

[isInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) determines if the specified *Object* is assignment-compatible with the object represented by *this Class*. You're passing it a class when it expects an object.

The opposite should work:

```
Spell.class.isInstance(spell)
```